# SKLabel avoid, use TextKit instead then create SKTexture?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, textkit

Staying in SpriteKit, is it possible to create more "artistic" text with the vastly greater control TextKit provides, and then (somehow) convert these strings to images so they can be used as SKSpriteNodes?

I ask because I'd like to do some more serious kerning stuff... much greater spacing, and a few other things that aren't possible with SKLabels, but are part of TextKit, but I'd like them to be bitmaps as soon as I'm done getting them to look the way I want.

But I can't find a way to turn A TextKit into an image.

Comment: Is this for dynamic text or static

Comment: @MobileBen I'd **assume** static, then once that's done and figured out, maybe find a way to make it work for dynamic text

Comment: Yes, static textual content, though I will be moving and scaling the final bitmap that results from it.

Comment: Although, as @Nik says, as soon as possible, I'd like to figure out how to animate kerning changes, too. But that's for another day. A different problem.

Comment: @Confused Hello man, I don't know what is your project with these labels and what are your purposes, but I speak about my personal experience. Remember you can also add new otf or ttf (true type font) to your project http://www.thomashanning.com/using-custom-fonts/ choosing a bizarre ttf or customized by you (with more space between letters..).

Comment: I'm trying for editable font properties inside SpriteKit. The below answer from bzz pretty much nails it, render from TypeKit into CGContext, grab the image, use it as a Texture for an SKSpriteNode. Another of the resident geniuses. It's a pity this can't be animated. But that'd require Apple to care about fonts and layout. It's pretty obvious that ship sailed with iOS 6 onwards and AutoLayout as a priority. "Just make more apps, please!" has been their message for the past few years, at the express expense of quality. @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: @Confused LOL, I'm totally agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw your text in a `CGContext`, then create a texture from it and assign that texture to a `SKSpriteNode`.

Here is an example from [this GitHub project](https://github.com/alex-alex/ASAttributedLabelNode):

```
class ASAttributedLabelNode: SKSpriteNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: size)
    }

    var attributedString: NSAttributedString! {
        didSet {
            draw()
        }
    }

    func draw() {
        guard let attrStr = attributedString else {
            texture = nil
            return
        }

        let scaleFactor = UIScreen.main.scale
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
        guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width * scaleFactor), height: Int(size.height * scaleFactor), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: Int(size.width * scaleFactor) * 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo) else {
            return
        }

        context.scaleBy(x: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor)
        context.concatenate(CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: size.height))
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)

        let strHeight = attrStr.boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil).height
        let yOffset = (size.height - strHeight) / 2.0
        attrStr.draw(with: CGRect(x: 0, y: yOffset, width: size.width, height: strHeight), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

        if let imageRef = context.makeImage() {
            texture = SKTexture(cgImage: imageRef)
        } else {
            texture = nil
        }

        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, and the excellent example of using `guard let...`, something I've just realised might be a very cool tool. Much nicer looking than `if let...`, too!